Definitions of discrimiant in function field case
In function field case, I have seen two different definitions of discriminant (of a point), I wonder if they are equivalent and how can one establish the relation of the normal discrimiant definition in number field. The setting is the following:
Let $B$ be a smooth connected curve of genus $q$ over some algebraically closed field $k$ of char $0$. Let $\pi: X \to B$ be a flat proper morphism with connected fibers and assume that $X$ isa regular surface. Let $g$ denote the genus of the generic fiber $C$ of $\pi$. An algebraic point $P$ on $C$ corresponds to the diagram

where $B'$ is a smooth connected projective cover of $B$. Let $q'$ denote the genus of $B'$.
Then we have two definitions of discriminant of the algebraic point $P$:

$d(P)=\dfrac{2q'-2}{[k(B'):k(B)]}$
$d(P)=\dfrac{2q'-2}{[(k(B))(P):k(B)]}-(2q-2)$

I am not sure why they are equivalent definitions. Maybe another question is for the normal logarithmic discriminant definition (like in algebraic number theory) $d(P)=\dfrac{\log|D_{k(P)/k}|}{[k(P):k]}$, why the function field analogue is indeed a "analogue" definition.
Anything is appreciated!
